# How to retrieve the data which is saved in the format of serialized XML string in a MySQL database using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a field in a MySQL table which is saved in the format of serialized XML string using a `SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0"?><XML-tree></XML-tree>')` function. How to retrieve the data to get the XML structure tree back to process the XML elements in PHP? thanks for your help

Comment: What is the exact literal value stored?

Comment: Retrieve the column with a query, then use an XML parser to extract the data. Make a note to yourself __not__ to store data this way again.

Comment: @HoboSapiens, I get the error message `String could not be parsed as XML` from my select query variable `simplexml_load_string($select)`

Comment: What is the value of $select?  This should be the result of a query made to MySQL to retrieve the XML.

Comment: @Sami You haven't posted any code. There could be a dozen reasons that lead to that message.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways. You need to first grab the mysql field which contains the xml data and use it this way for an example. When you say "retrieve the data to get the XML structure tree back" you need to literally get the field xml data with mysql_fetch_array or assoc and get it into a variable. Lets say this was your xml data in MySQL DB:

```
$xml_data_from_mysql = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resultset>
  <row>
    <name>Sami</name>
    <sex>M</sex>
  </row>
  <row>
    <name>Sami_F</name>
    <sex>F</sex>
  </row>
</resultset>';

//Use simplexml_load_string to process xml data
$simple  = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$array  = json_decode( json_encode($simple) , 1);
print_r($array);

**Output will be:**

Array
(
    [row] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Sami
                    [sex] => M
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Sami_F
                    [sex] => F
                )
        )
)
```

Once its converted to an array, you can manipulate the data however you want. Or you can directly use php xml parser; I prefer to convert xml into an array for easy handling.

Comment: make sure there is <?xml notation in your xml field. Get rid of everything else before and after, if there's ton of data use mysql replace string function to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
simplexml_load_string
```

to create a SimpleXMLElement object from the string saved in the DB.

Comment: `simplexml_load_string` does not work and returns `String could not be parsed as XML...`

Comment: Usually you get that error cause your XML string is not valid. Be sure the xml is valid.

Comment: make sure there is <?xml notation in your xml field. Get rid of everything else before and after, if there's ton of data use mysql replace string function to do that.